# How do I extract the version number portion from the version string?

Tags: scripts

How do I extract the version number from `string=customer-asset-tag-1.0.2.9`?

Desired result:

```
Component= customer-asset-tag
version number=1.0.2.9
```

Answer (score 7):

There are many ways of doing this, for example:

- bash and similar shells (see [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) for more info)

  ```
  $ string=customer-asset-tag-1.0.2.9
  $ echo -e "Component: ${string:0:18}\nVersion: ${string:19}"
  Component: customer-asset-tag
  Version: 1.0.2.9
  ```
- `awk`

  ```
  $ echo $string | awk -F- -v OFS=- '{print "Component: "$1,$2,$3; print "Version: "$4}'
  Component: customer-asset-tag
  Version: 1.0.2.9
  ```

  Here, we are setting `awk`'s field delimiter to `-` (this is used to define fields, the 1st field is `$1`, the 2nd `$2` etc). We are also setting the output field separator to `-` so it will print correctly.
- `perl`

  ```
  $ echo $string | perl -ne '/(.*)-([^-]+)/; print "Component: $1\nVersion: $2"'
  Component: customer-asset-tag
  Version: 1.0.2.9
  ```

  This is the most robust and general of the three approaches since it simply looks for the longest string of non `-` characters and saves that as the version and everything before the version until the last `-` and saves that as a component.

Comment: no need to represent $ before commands .

Comment: @AvinashRaj that is the classic format used in the *nix world to represent the prompt. It helps differentiate which part of a text block is the command and which is the command's output. I tend to use it whenever I show both a command and its output.

Comment: @AvinashRaj While re generally frown upon prompts here, terndon is not giving commands to the user as much as quoting output, so it's fine.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following in terminal,

```bsh
$ string=customer-asset-tag-1.0.2.9
$ ver=$(echo $string | awk -F- '{print $NF}')
$ Component=${string/-$ver/}
$ echo "version number=$ver"
version number=1.0.2.9
$ echo "Component=$Component"
Component=customer-asset-tag
```

or inside a shell script,

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
string=customer-asset-tag-1.0.2.9
ver=$(echo $string | awk -F- '{print $NF}')
Component=${string/-$ver/}
echo "version number=$ver"
echo "Component=$Component"
```

Answer (score 3):

To extract version number

```
echo "customer-asset-tag-1.0.2.9"  | sed 's/[a-z-]//g'
```

Perl way of doing it

```
echo "customer-asset-tag-1.0.2.9"  | perl -ne  '/([a-z-]*)-([\d+.+]*)/; print "Component= $1\nVersion= $2\n"'
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `awk` command,

```
$ string=customer-asset-tag-1.0.2.9
$ echo "Component= "$(echo $string | awk '{print substr($1,1,18)}') && echo "Version number="$(echo $string | awk '{print substr($1,20)}')
Component= customer-asset-tag
Version number=1.0.2.9
```

Description:

- `echo $string` - displays the value assigned to  variable string.
- `echo $string | awk '{print substr($1,1,18)}'`

  - | - standard output was fed as input to the following command.
  - `substr($1,1,18)`- From the input take the first column and display only the characters starting from the position 1 to 18 to the standard output.
- `echo $string | awk '{print substr($1,20)}'`

  - Display the characters starting from the 20th position in the first column from the standard input.

---

```
awk '{print substr($x,y,z)}'
```

x - column number
y - starting position
z - Ending position